# How to send a POST request to get my reCAPTCHA form to work?

Tags: php, recaptcha

I would like to implement [Google reCAPTCHA button](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html) for my boss's contact forms. I've integrated the necessary code into the html but I'm having trouble with step 2, server side integration:

[image: Google Instructions]

This is the web page where I'm testing the code: http://agentboris.com/listings/85bloorstreeteast-book.php

Can someone please explain how to code Step 2 and where I should integrate it (i.e. whether it needs to be coded into the webpage file, or the PHP form script file)?

Comment: you hid your form recaptcha on the page. also, submit isn't working - gets you on a 404

Answer (score 1):

You can perform server side validation this way

```
  // grab recaptcha library
 require_once "recaptchalib.php";
 $reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret);

 // if submitted check response
 if ($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) {
  $response = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse(
    $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
    $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
  );
 }
```

Comment: Here is full source code with demo code. Check this one https://github.com/google/recaptcha